# Custom Related field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've a serializer that receives and returns a list of strings. 
Those strings internally are model instances.

In the serializer, when I receive a new `types` list I've to check if the type exists, if exists associate it to the other model otherwise create a new instance and associate it.

I can do it using a custom `RelatedField`

```
class TypeRelatedField(serializers.StringRelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return Type.objects.get(name=data)
        except Type.DoesNotExist:
            return Type.objects.create(name=data)
```

and in the serializer that receives the types list

```
types = TypeRelatedField(many=True, required=False)
```

so that if the type exists it will be returned, otherwise created. I'm not sure if it's the right place to do this, maybe I should do this in the `create` and `update` method?

Answer (score 0):

If it works and doesn't break anything else, then it's a right thing to do ;) If you have to do this an all methods that manipulates model (create, update), then it's probably best to do it here, for DRY reasons. If not, do it in create or update. But if you need it for example only on create, you should write it in create, if only in update, then it should go there.